# I want to organize my listbox by greatest to least, but organizing it takes a long time. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to organize my listbox from numbers greatest to least, but when I execute it, it takes approximately 2 minutes for it to happen. It works just fine, but it takes a long time.

I'm lost on what to do. It's the only way I know how to do it. It would be very appreciated if there was a better way to do it.

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clearFile(strPathSort);
            clearFile(strPathSkips);


            for(int i3 = 0; i3 <= countLinesInFile(strPathList); i3++)
            {
                int intMostEpisodes = int.MinValue;
                int intIndex = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i <= countLinesInFile(strPathList); i++)
                {
                    bool booOk = true;
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strPathSkips);
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= countLinesInFile(strPathSkips); i2++)
                    {
                        if (sr.Peek() != -1)
                        {
                        if (i == int.Parse(sr.ReadLine().ToString()))
                            booOk = false;
                        }
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                    if (findEpisodesOfLine(i) > intMostEpisodes && booOk == true)
                    {
                        intMostEpisodes = findEpisodesOfLine(i);
                        intIndex = i;
                    }
                }
                StreamWriter swSkips = new StreamWriter(strPathSkips, true);
                swSkips.WriteLine(intIndex);
                swSkips.Close();
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strPathSort, true);
                sw.WriteLine(intIndex);
                sw.Close();
            }
            StreamWriter sw3 = new StreamWriter(strPathSorted, false);
            StreamReader sr4 = new StreamReader(strPathSort);
            for (int i4 = 0; i4 <= countLinesInFile(strPathSort); i4++)
            {
                if (sr4.Peek() != -1)
                sw3.WriteLine(readSpecificLine(strPathList, int.Parse(sr4.ReadLine())));
            }
            sw3.Close();
            sr4.Close();
            addInfo(strPathSorted, lbListe, true);
        }
```

Comment: Your question says you are trying to sort a listbox. But **none of your code** is interacting with a listbox.

Comment: lbliste = listbox
; countLinesInFile counts how many lines there are in a text file.

Comment: Why do you keep opening and closing the streamwriters inside the loop? Why not open them **before** the loop and keep them open?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using `ListBox.Sorted`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. In particular, the contents of `addInfo`.

Comment: @OkIsee The expectation is that you will respond to comments.

Comment: Can you edit your post and dump a copy of the raw text file you are trying to import and have sorted.  If private data, you can just fake some of it, but try to keep in proper context and layout for us to review.  What from the sample data you provide is the basis of the data sorting as now it is just a guess.  Also, sample context/file names to your strPath and strSkip variables

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are going to your file every time you call `countLinesInFile(strPathSort)`  thats going to be awfully slow.  In fact you have a lot of file operations inside your loops that keep getting repeated.  Far better to hold all of them in memory and write them at the end.

instead do

```
var lineCount = countLinesInFile(strPathList);
```

then use it in your loops...

```
for(int i3 = 0; i3 <= lineCount; i3++)
```

Comment: This worked, but after the third line it kept looping it the third one over and over again.